# Install Ubuntu from a virtual box image

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Is it possible to install Ubuntu from a pre-configured VirtualBox installation?

If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Maybe, but why?  Using the Ubuntu ISO, it generally takes about 20 minutes to install and fully configure an Ubuntu installation.

Comment: That's because I'd like to install some programs first and test them before the installation. And In case everything works as expected, I'd like to use the VirtualBox image, and save me some time.

Comment: So, you are building a VB, installing programs and testing, and then you want to roll that VB out to your users?

Comment: @CharlesGreen You're almost there. In fact, I want to replace the actual Ubuntu installation I have on my PC by that one I just configured on the Virtual Box.

Comment: OK - I think [this is what you are looking for](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/) - I have not used this myself, and according to the launchpad website it is no longer developed or supported.  A second program, 'mondorescue' ceased development in 2016.  Perhaps clonezilla?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I see. So this has more to do with creating an image from the system than the VirtualBox itself. So all I have to do is configure my ubuntu installation, install all the programs I want, create an image with Clonezilla and restore it to my computer. Is this it? I'm sorry for the noobish question, I really don't know much about this.

Comment: I've never done it myself - I find it quite easy to install to virtual devices, and I have create scripts that to the installation of programs that I want to have on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in at least two manners.

First, assuming that you built and installed your VM on at least one computer, your can *Export you VM as an appliance* from the first computer, and *Import VM from appliance* on as many target machine as you wish.  This would be quick and painless.

Or

You can create a custom installation ISO, as detained in [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

There are undoubtably other methods to do this function.  There are nine answers at this link: https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer